# Python: Change Step Loops Dynamically in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## I have records in a spreadsheet and I need to partition group by ID_CLI.

**My code is**

```
Import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('ReadSheet.xlsx')
step = 5
count = 0

for i in range(0, len(data), step):
    df = data[i:i + step]
    count += 1

    df.to_excel('SpreadSheet_'+count+'.xlsx')
```

I need read the step in next position of the ID_CLI (step 6), and if is equal to the current one (step 5) it iterates +1 in my step, otherwise step = 5. Repeat in all records of my SpreadSheet keeping my original step = 5, and Iterates if next (ID_CLI) is equal current one

**My Original SpreadSheet**

I need some condicition like this:

```
if ID_CLI[step + 1] == ID_CLI[step]:
      step += 1                
else:
      step = step
```

```
POSITION    ID_CLI  NAME_CLI
1           1       Bruce Wayne
2           1       Bruce Wayne
3           2       Prakash Dahal
4           2       Prakash Dahal
5           3       Peter Parker
6           3       Peter Parker
7           4       Black Panther
8           4       Black Panther
9           4       Black Panther
10          4       Black Panther
11          5       Tony Stark
12          6       Doctor Strange
13          6       Doctor Strange
14          6       Doctor Strange
15          6       Doctor Strange
16          6       Doctor Strange
17          6       Doctor Strange
18          6       Doctor Strange
19          7       Ciclops
20          7       Ciclops
21          7       Ciclops
22          7       Ciclops
23          7       Ciclops
24          8       Nocturn
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        
**SpreadSheet_1.xlsx**      
POSITION    ID_CLI  NAME_CLI
1           1       Bruce Wayne
2           1       Bruce Wayne
3           2       Prakash Dahal
4           2       Prakash Dahal
5           3       Peter Parker # step = 5 and ID_CLI Equals next ID_CLI 
6           3       Peter Parker # step = 6 and ID_CLI Different next ID_CLI from step 7


**SpreadSheet_2.xlsx**      
POSITION    ID_CLI  NAME_CLI
7           4       Black Panther
8           4       Black Panther
9           4       Black Panther
10          4       Black Panther
11          5       Tony Stark # step = 5 and ID_CLI Different next ID_CLI from step 6


**SpreadSheet_3.xlsx**      
POSITION    ID_CLI  NAME_CLI
12          6       Doctor Strange
13          6       Doctor Strange
14          6       Doctor Strange
15          6       Doctor Strange
16          6       Doctor Strange # step = 5 and ID_CLI Equals next ID_CLI from step 6
17          6       Doctor Strange # step = 6 and ID_CLI Equals next ID_CLI from step 7
18          6       Doctor Strange # step = 7 and ID_CLI Different next ID_CLI from step 8


**SpreadSheet_4.xlsx**      
POSITION    ID_CLI  NAME_CLI
19          7       Ciclops
20          7       Ciclops
21          7       Ciclops
22          7       Ciclops
23          7       Ciclops # step = 5 and ID_CLI Different next ID_CLI from step 6


**SpreadSheet_4.xlsx**
POSITION    ID_CLI  NAME_CLI
24          8       Nocturn # End Records
```

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. Can you explain exactly how you expect to obtain those two dataframes from your original dataframe `data`?

Comment: Sorry, I posted a wrong answer.

Comment: Dont Worry @JackDeeth

Comment: Sounds like you want a `groupby`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The result is 2 spreadsheet df.to_excel('SpreadSheet 1',  index=False)

Comment: @C.Nivs yes, I'ld want `groupby ID_CLI` and partition all records changing my `step`. When my `step = 5` and ` previous position of the `ID_CLI` is equal to the current one it iterates +1.

Comment: So you want 5 unique names in the first dataframe and the remaining in the second?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, Thats Right.

Comment: But your "Spreadsheet 1" only has 4 unique names...

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I need that when it checks only position 5, and it checks if position 4 is equal to position 5. If it is equal, it iterates +1, otherwise step = 5

Comment: @LuardeJulio your question is still quite unclear. can you elaborate it by adding more rows in your dataframe?

Comment: Make an explicit example with expected output please.

Comment: Now is clear? @PrakashDahal

Comment: Now is clear? @Shayan

Comment: No it's not! You stated **output**! I said make a simple and small example of what you have and **your expected output**!

Comment: What is unclear in this example @Shayan?

Comment: why nocturn is not in spread_3? also can you clear what `iterates +1`  means?

Comment: Because in spread_3 Nocturn have `ID_CLI` different Ciclops  and step = 5 @PrakashDahal

Comment: can you clarify terms like `steps` and `iterates`? Also try to clarify why `bruce wayne` and `black_panther` are in spread_1 despite having different ID_CLI.

Comment: If you look at the `POSITION`, it represents which row it is on in the worksheet. My `step` is where my sheet will be split.

`Bruce Wayne` is in the last record of `step`, but the next record in `POSITION` is equal to the last record of `step`, so it is in spread_1, when it is no longer `Bruce Wayne` a new worksheet is generated . @PrakashDahal

Comment: @LuardeJulio can you add 2 more `Black Panther` below that Black Panther and show us what you output would look like?

Comment: Done @PrakashDahal

Comment: Done @PrakashDahal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
"""
- creates chunk for size of 5
- if duplicate data is in 5th place and 6th place, it will increase chunk size until the final duplicate data place is found and creates its chunk.
"""

step = 5
a = 0

df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
df['POSITION'] = df['POSITION'].astype(int)
df['ID_CLI'] = df['ID_CLI'].astype(int)
df['POS_INDEX'] = df['POSITION']
df = df.set_index('POS_INDEX')

while True:
    if step >= len(df):
        a += 1
        df.loc[1:step].to_excel(f'SpreadSheet_{a}.xlsx', index=False)
        break
        
    if df.loc[step,'NAME_CLI'] == df.loc[step+1,'NAME_CLI']:
        while df.loc[step,'NAME_CLI'] == df.loc[step+1,'NAME_CLI']:
            step += 1
        a += 1
        df.loc[1:step].to_excel(f'SpreadSheet_{a}.xlsx', index=False)
        df.drop(list(range(1,step+1)), axis=0,inplace=True) #droping chunk to create new df
        df.index = list(range(1,len(df)+1))
        df.index.name = 'POS_INDEX'
        step=5
    else:
        step = 5
        a += 1
        df.loc[1:step].to_excel(f'SpreadSheet_{a}.xlsx', index=False)
        df.drop(list(range(1,step+1)), axis=0,inplace=True)
        df.index = list(range(1,len(df)+1))
        df.index.name = 'POS_INDEX'
```